# Unable to get a temperature reading from CPU

Tags: cpu, temperature

Following instructions over [here](http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1669698), I tried to get something running to show the temperature of my AMD A6 6400K. Unfortunately, the output I get is the following:

```
TurionPowerControl 0.44-rc2 (export)
Turion Power States Optimization and Control - by blackshard

Detected processor: Family 15h (Bulldozer/Interlagos/Valencia) Processor
Machine has 1 nodes
Processor has 1 cores
Processor has 7 p-states
Processor has 2 boost states
Processor temperature slew rate:9.0°C

Temperature table:
Node 0  C0:0

Done.
```

This doesn't tell me anything, unfortunately, and lm-sensors also shows an unrealistic temperature reading near freezing point, when the BIOS reports an idle temperature of about 30 degrees (C). The temperature readout from byobu also shows unrealistic temperatures of about 10 degrees.

So either I'm doing something wrong, I perhaps I need to find another program. Any suggestions?

I'm trying to figure out why the computer freezes after a few minutes of GPU-intensive work (GPU built into CPU), but I can't tell if it's the temperature or not, since I have no readouts.

Comment: [This](http://lm-sensors.org/wiki/FAQ/Chapter3#MyBIOSreportsamuchhigherCPUtemperaturethanyourmodules) part of the lm-sensors faq might be relevant

Comment: Alright, that explains a few things, but then how can I get the right temperature?